# how do i change a file extension on qt

Tags: c++, qt, file-extension, fileinfo

I have a piece of code to download a file from server. However, due to server constraint, I can not put .exe file at server. So I rename my XXX.exe file to XXX.alt(just a random extension) and put it on server. 
Now my code can download XXX.alt, but how can I change the file name from XXX.alt back to XXX.exe when in QT environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use rename function from 'stdio.h'.

```
char oldname[] ="XXX.alt";
char newname[] ="XXX.exe";
result= rename( oldname , newname );
if ( result == 0 )
  puts ( "File successfully renamed" );
else
  perror( "Error renaming file" );
```

Comment: In Qt this would be `QFile::rename(const QString & oldName, const QString & newName)` although the c code you posted should work fine.

Comment: both of you two are right. Thanks. and I found out we donot even need put the oldName. we can just QFile(const QString & newName)

Answer (score 22):

Use QFileInfo to get the path without the last extension then append the new extension.

```
QFileInfo info(fileName);
QString strNewName = info.path() + "/" + info.completeBaseName() + ".exe";
```

Comment: I think this needs a separator: `QString strNewName = info.path() + "/" + info.completeBaseName() + ".exe";` On Linux, the path returned from `QFileInfo::path()` does not include a separator at the end.

Comment: @Mitch Thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to find the last `'.'`, and replace the substring from that position to the end with the substring you want.

Exactly how to do it, there are many ways using both [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [`QString`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html), as both support finding characters in the string (and doing a search from the end to the beginning as well), and replace substrings.

Answer (score 0):

**Prefer to use baseName()**

```
QFileInfo info(fileName);
QString strNewName = info.path() + info.baseName() + ".exe";
```

---

```
QString QFileInfo::completeBaseName () const
Returns file name with shortest extension removed (file.tar.gz -> file.tar)

QString QFileInfo::baseName () const
Returns file name with longest extension removed (file.tar.gz -> file)
```